# git lost some branches, and show not a directory

Tags: git

I created `fix/a`, `fix/b` branches, but `git branch` show nothing

and some weird logs:

```
$ file .git/refs/heads/fix
.git/refs/heads/fix: directory
$ ls -l .git/refs/heads/fix                                                                                                                                   
ls: cannot open directory .git/refs/heads/fix: Not a directory
```

what is wrong , how to fix?

```
$ stat .git/logs/refs/heads/fix
  File: ‘.git/logs/refs/heads/fix’
  Size: 136             Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 25h/37d Inode: 4694        Links: 1
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/     worker)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: system_u:object_r:vmblock_t:s0
Access: 2018-05-22 19:19:10.000000000 +0900
Modify: 2018-05-28 19:58:11.000000000 +0900
Change: 2018-05-28 19:58:11.000000000 +0900
 Birth: -
```

Comment: How did you create those branches?

Comment: `git checkout -b fix/a`

Comment: To create a branch `git branch <branch-name>` (this creates a branch but doesn't actually *move* you there). To create a new branch and go there (make it the active branch): `git checkout -b <branch-name>`.

Comment: What does `stat .git/refs/heads/fix` say? Is it Linux?

Comment: @max630 update stat, it is virtualbox linux guest on a MacOS Host, mount by shared folder

Comment: "shared folder" mounts have problems. Your best bet is not to use them at all; your second-best is to use them only minimally (e.g., never store a Git repository in one).

Comment: I would not go as far as @torek but obviosly this issue is very closely tied to the fact that it is a mount. As you can see, even basic file operation fails to work. You are probably better to ask at superuser.com, and they probably will ask way more information

Comment: @max630: I have the same setup (Mac host with VirtualBox Linux instance). I have a few shared items I use mainly read-only. I was trying to use shared areas to work in and had all kinds of weird issues (mostly inexplicable slowness but things clearly did not work right). There are some indications that NFS mounts do work, but setting them up opens a lot of potential security issues; I decided to limit the VBox to local space and it's been reliable since then.